# How to show emails sent to a client without adding noise to normal activity section?

Tags: email, appexchange, app

We're periodically sending out automated emails to clients from our own email server. We BCC a company account on every send. Right now sales reps have no way to see when those emails go out (they don't have access to the BCC'd account).

We *could* link the emails to salesforce such that all email are logged as completed tasks, but this would overwhelm the activity history section in salesforce and make it difficult for reps to quickly glance at other, non-automated touch points with clients.

How can we create a new view within either a Contact or Account record so that a rep can see a list of the last several automated emails that went out to a client's email address? Ideally this would be done outside of the normal activity history section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can enable Enhanced emails functionality. This enables a new object in salesforce where all emails sent from/to salesforce are saved . You can write triggers and build reports on this object. Add these reports as dashboard components in a dashboard.
I didn't understand what you meant by overwhelm the menu, but this works like any other custom object.

**Update** : 
You can use inbound/outbound email service feature for this. This would require some apex code to be written but basically using this, incoming/outgoing emails can be processed using apex code and saved in a different custom object instead of task (activity history related list)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated some of the terminology here to make it more clear what we are looking for. We want to keep the emails out of the activity history so ideally this would be an app or another related list that we could create that would aggregate emails sent from a particular email address to this client. If you have any additional insight that would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: Great. Please select as best answer, if that works. Thx